# Inject values in $request->input() from controller Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Is there a way to do something like this in the controller?

```
$request->input(['new_field_name' => 'new_val']);
```

I've googled a lot, but the only thing I've found was related to Laravel's 4.x formatInput method, which has been removed from the 5.x

I need to inject a specific field in the $request when the request has passed the validation, then save the new record in the db.

Any clue? Thanks to everyone!

Comment: **Did you try it**??

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, but it doesn't work.. still no errors though...

Comment: Try to do `$inputs = $request->all();` then `$inputs['new_field_name'] = 'new_val'` !

Comment: @Maraboc Mmmh! This should solve the problem,  I'll try this when I'll be back home, then I'll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [`merge`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge) is the right tool for this.

Example of a typical use case (saving a slug given a title):

```
$request->merge(['slug' => Str::slug($request->title)]);
```